# Soldier from the near future in a war with Arab fighters, time travels to the past

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read a paperback novel at a library about 10 - 15 years ago and want to find it again.  However, I can not remember the name or author of the novel, and can not find it in the library.   It was about a soldier from the near future who time traveled into the past.  In the time he was from there was a war on (or terrorism?) in which the enemy were Arab fighters who belonged to a group with a name something like Unite.  I would appreciate it if any one could help me identify the name and/or author of the novel.  Thanks!

Extra details, as requested:  The time period the soldier traveled into was the present day of when the novel was published, likely sometime in the 1990's.  Right now I can not remember other details.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This description seems pretty broad. Do you remember any other details?

Comment: Do you remember anything about the period in his past he traveled to?